How to test that function inside HOC is called with proper props?
I have this code:
//in "updateProps.jsx":
export const function update(props){ some code here };

export const function withUpdatedProps(element) {
    const Wrapper = (props) => {
        const updatedProps = update(props);
        return <WrappedComponent {…updatedProps} />;
    };

    return Wrapper;
}

I want to test in unit test that function "update" was called.
import * as updateProps from './updateProps';

const TestComponent = () => <p>Hello World!</p>

TestCompnent.defaultProps = { color: "red" }

const withUpdatedProps = updateProps.withUpdatedProps;

describe("updateProps", () => {
    it("does whatever", () => {
       const updateSpy = jest.spyOn(updateProps, 'update');
       const UpdatedTestComponent = withUpdatedProps(TestComponent);
       
       render(<UpdatedTestComponent/>)

       expect(updateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(TestComponent.defaultProps);
    });
});

Jest keeps saying that number of calls is 0. I also tried by mocking 'update' and the result was the same. I need to test with what props is the component rendered. Can anyone help?
When I debug I have impression that "update" is called only when creating UpdatedTestComponent (with empty object as props) but not when rendering it.

I believe the issue you're facing may be caused by the fact update() is defined and exported from the same module as your HOC.
This means when your HOC is created, it closes in a reference to the real update() function.
One way to get around this is to drop jest.SpyOn() and use jest.mock() instead. Another crucial change is to move update() into its own file, so it can be exported and mocked independently.
I've provided a Codeandbox below, which includes several console.log() statements to let you see which version of update() is scoped within your Component and test file. You'll notice in this version, invokrender(<UpdatedTestComponent/>) will invoke the expected mocked function.
You can also you this same logging tactic in your original code to observe render(<UpdatedTestComponent/>) triggering a call to the REAL update() rather than mocked version you expect.
CodeSanbox Example
While I've provided a workaround to your problem, please note this style of mocking within unit tests is a hot topic for debate, as many developers argue you shouldn't be testing implementation details within a unit test.
I highly recommend reviewing source material from Kent C. Dodds (creator of react-testing-library) as he offers a really valuable perspective on testing.
